# Unable to modify xaml controls following NFC tag read

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a method that adds a label with some text to an existing xaml StackLayout.

The method is called from a couple of places, an event fired by xaml ListView and an NFC tag read. In both scenarios, the method is hit in the code-behind.

The methods both call another method that creates the label and adds it on screen. The one that originates from the ListView event works fine but the one from the NFC tag does nothing. It passes over each row of code without causing an exception but does not add anything to the screen. I can see after this that the child count of the StackLayout is 1 and remains as 1 if you do it again.

The NFC method:

```
public async void HandleNFC(string convertedtag)
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        var mp = (MainPage)App.Current.MainPage;
        Label sl1 = mp.CurrentPage.FindByName<Label>("timeLabel");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }

    Label sl = timeLabel;
    string time = sl.Text;

    PeopleLocationsForUserRoot peoplelocationforuser = await WebDataAccess.GetPeopleLocationForUser(UserInfoRepository.GetUserName(), _locationID);
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(time);

    long timeticks = (long)((dt.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - DatetimeMinTimeTicks) / 10000);
    getServerTime();
    string name = "";

    try
    {
        foreach (var person in peoplelocationforuser.locationPeople)
        {
            if (person.TATokenValue == convertedtag)
            {
                var action = await DisplayActionSheet(person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName, "Cancel", null, "IN", "OUT");
                string act = action;
                string formattedact = act;
                int swipedirection = 0;

                name = person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName;

                if (act == "IN")
                {
                    formattedact = "in";
                    swipedirection = 1;
                }

                if (act == "OUT")
                {
                    formattedact = "out";
                    swipedirection = 0;
                }

                if (act != "Cancel")
                {
                    result = SwipeRepository.ClockUserInOut(person.EB_Counter, _locationID, swipedirection, dt, timeticks, 1, UserInfoRepository.GetLatt(), UserInfoRepository.GetLongi());

                    addToReadout(name, time, formattedact);
                }
            }

        }
        if (name == "")
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Tag Error", "Tag not recognised", "cancel");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ErrorRepository.InsertError(ex.ToString());
    }

    await WebDataAccess.SaveSwipesToCloud();

}
```

The 'addToReadOut' method that it calls:

```
public void addToReadout(string name, string time, string inout)
{
    try
    {
        Label label1 = new Label { Text = name + " Successfully clocked " + inout + " @ " + time, TextColor = Color.Black };

        try
        {
            readOut.Children.Add(label1);
            StackLayout sl = this.FindByName<StackLayout>("readOut");
            sl.Children.Add(label1);
            sl.Focus();
            timeLabel.Text = "test";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
       // StackLayout sl = mp.CurrentPage.FindByName<StackLayout>("readOut");

        if (readOut.Children.Count() < 6)
        {

            readOut.Children.Add(label1);
            readOut.Children.Count();
        }
        else
        {
            readOut.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            readOut.Children.Add(label1);
            readOut.Children.Count();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ErrorRepository.InsertError(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

You can see that I have also tried to modify the object called 'timelabel' but does also does not change on screen.

The must be something different happening following the NFC event which is causing an issue here but I can't find what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

You NFC event is firing on a background thread; your UI updates need to happen on the UI thread

```
Device.BeingInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
  // UI Code goes here
});
```

Comment: I just added your code to surround the code that makes the modifications but it does nothing I'm afraid.

Comment: should this code be inserted, somewhere more specific?